# Don't see up arrow after commit in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, commit, egit

Usually when we make commit we see uparrow with number near respository or folder in eclipse.  But for some reason I don't see any up arrow after commit.  Is there any setting I need to do enable to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Open

> Window->Preferences

from menu. Then choose

> Team->Git->Label Decorations

The button "Restore Defaults" will bring back the arrows you miss; see Preview Project on the same preferences page.